# Is it possible to request read access to a specific content Uri?

Tags: android

## Background

I have a journal app that allows the user to attach photos to entries from the camera or storage. The app stores references to the image files in a database in the form of *content://* Uri strings. This seems to work reliably.

Now I want to create a free version of the app that is more basic, but I need to include a mechanism to import the data into the more advanced app should the user choose to upgrade. This is easily accomplished with an exported ContentProvider, but attempting to read from the content Uris results in a SecurityException since it is a different app.

## Question

Is it possible to request persistable read access to a known Uri? I know how to use `takePersistableUriPermission` on the Uri returned by an `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` Intent, but I don't see a way to do that with a specific Uri.

## Potential Solutions

1. Use a single app with an In-App Purchase to unlock the full features. The reasons I want to avoid that is that it relies on Google Play and the file size will be unnecessarily large for the free version.
2. Use the same `sharedUserId` for both apps so their permissions are shared. This is not possible in this case since existing users will not be able to upgrade.
3. Convert the `content://` Uris to `file://` Uris and create a new content Uri in the receiving app. Of course this is not possible with all content Uris but it is better than nothing.

Comment: "Is it possible to request persistable read access to a known Uri?" -- why do you need it to be persistable? An import is usually a one-time thing.

Comment: The app needs to be able to read the content every time an entry is viewed, not just during import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to my question appears to be no.

As far as I can tell from the documentation, it appears that you have to be offered persistable Uri permissions by the content provider use [`takePersistableUriPermission`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#takePersistableUriPermission%28android.net.Uri,%20int%29) on the data returned by an `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` Intent. There doesn't appear to be a way to make a request for permissions for access to a particular Uri.

To solve this problem I decided to treat content Uris as volatile and copy the data to a file in an public app-specific directory on the external storage. Then I just store the file names and reconstruct the full path when I need it. This makes the database agnostic to the file structure and the data more portable. The downside is that it duplicates data and uses more storage space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must implement the No. 1
You can do several versions with "flavors" Gradle:
It's nothing complicated:
build a flavor paid (whit all).
build a free flavor (smaller).

```
productFlavors {
paid {
    applicationId = "com.vogella.android.gradlebuildflavors.paid"
    versionName = "1.0-paid"
}

free {
    applicationId = "com.vogella.android.gradlebuildflavors.free"
    versionName = "1.0-free"
}
}
```

A tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html

Comment: That is how you create two separate apps that share some common code, which is exactly what I have done already. They are still treated as two distinct apps and an in-app purchase won't be able to upgrade the free version unless it includes all the code.